# Receiver won't work when app is closed

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

In my app I have a broadcast receiver that receive a message from GCM push message. It's works correctly when application is open. My app successfully generate Notification with my message and then broadcast it and when my MainActivity comes receives that message and shows.

but the problem stars when app is closed. Notification is generates successfully with message but when mainActivity runs there is nothing to receive.

I wanna sync my receiver with my app so that if a message comes and my app is close or not it must shows my message. but I tried to register another receiver outside of my activity with it's own class like:

```
public class MahdiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

that registered in manifest.
but it wont sync to my Activity cause I need more extra intent to putextra my message for syncing. but in this way when my app is open it not works. cause i get extra needs my acticity close and open again. so what is the best way?

this my MainActivity with receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("LOG", "unreciver");
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

            /**
             * Take appropriate action on this message
             * depending upon your app requirement
             * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
             * */

            //Showing received message
            //lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n");
            Log.i("LOG", "unreciver messsage:"+newMessage);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loadReciverDialog(newMessage);
            // Releasing wake lock
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };
```

this is the part of service that receive message from GCM and Create notification:

```
     @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

            Log.i("LOG", "GCM service Message "+message);

            displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message);
        }

 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        Log.i("LOG", "genetaret notify");
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");


        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

and this part display message:

```
  static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Log.i("LOG", "commonutils msg="+message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
```

You're creating your BroadcastReceiver at runtime -- obviously it cannot receive events if your App is closed, because it does not exist at that point.

To receive events when your App is closed, you need to create a class that extends BroadcastReceiver, and then register this class in AndroidManifest.xml .

You might want to check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).

Comment: I make changes and new receiver with class and register it but still have problems passing parameters with main activity.  I wanna ask to how to register this receiver (receiver of main activity) so that it can used right.

Comment: problem is syncing receiver with main activity